# show that $\alpha\beta \leq \frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\alpha^2+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\beta^2$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

let $\varepsilon >0$. show that $\forall \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$

$\alpha\beta \leq \frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\alpha^2+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\beta^2.$

Its looks like holder inequality with $p=2$ and $q=2$.

some hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Move the term on the left hand side to the right, and you get a perfect square.  This just requires factorization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \left( \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt \varepsilon} - \beta  \sqrt \varepsilon \right)^2 \geq 0  $$

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM inequality (or Cauchy-Schwarz inequality or Holder inequality with $n=1$),

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\alpha^2}{\epsilon}+\epsilon \beta^2\right) \geq \sqrt{\frac{\alpha^2}{\epsilon} \cdot \epsilon \beta^2} = \alpha \beta$$